# Design patterns for dynamic-context-dependent operators (e.g. for modular arithmetic)?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, operator-overloading, language-design

This is a certain software engineering and language design problem I've constantly run into that I don't have a good solution for in *any* language. I'm most interested in a C++ solution, but solutions in other (hopefully lexically-scoped) languages would also be interesting to consider.

Here's an example. Let's say I have some piece of code, like maybe this:

```
template<class T, class F>
T foo(T a, T b, T c, T d, F func) { return func() / (a * d - b * c); }
```

I argue that the caller **should** be able to use `foo` with modular arithmetic as well as regular arithmetic.

In other words, for an appropriate definition of `finite_field`, in an ideal world, this **should** evaluate the code above in a finite field rather than in the field of real numbers:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    finite_field<int> scoped_field(argc /* let's say this is my modulus */);
    return foo(1, 2, 3, 4, []{ return +1; }) + foo(4, 3, 2, 1, []{ return -1; });
}
```

Yet, clearly, this doesn't work, because nothing inside `foo` (and specifically, none of the operators) is aware of the arithmetic context imposed by `scoped_field`.

*All* the solutions I'm aware of are quite ugly:

1. Stop using arithmetic operators altogether.
   Use `add(x, y)` instead of `x + y`, `div(x, y)` instead of `x / y`, etc.
   Then maybe put all of these inside an `Arithmetic` class of some sort and use `this` to access the current "arithmetic context".

   Pros: It works, and doesn't require storing excess data.

   Cons: Requires editing `foo`, which arguably should not be necessary, and at the same time makes it much less pleasing and much more difficult to read and write.
2. Define a custom `ModInt` type that wraps an `int`, store the modulus inside *each* number, and overload the operator for that type to read the modulus from one of it input arguments.

   Pros: It works, and it doesn't require modifying the body of `foo`.

   Cons: Inefficient and error-prone -- each modulus is stored inside *each* integer, meaning there's potential for conflict bugs at runtime, as well as an obvious O(n) space inefficiency. Not to mention that the evaluation context isn't a property of the numbers, but rather a property of the operators themselves.
3. Store the "current context" inside a thread-local variable, and overload the operators to behave differently depending on the context.

   Pros: It works (kind of). And it doesn't waste space or require modifying `foo`.

   Cons: Ugly, less portable, and either non-reentrant or error-prone depending on how it's implemented (it'd contaminate callees' arithmetic operator contexts)

So, **I literally don't know of any solution that is readable, portable, *and* maintainable**.
It seems like I fundamentally have to give up one of those, as far as I can tell.

---

#### My questions:

1. Is this a commonly-encountered or well-known problem?
2. Does it have an elegant solution in *any* reasonably popular language? If so, which ones, and how?
3. Can it specifically be solved in C++? Is there some kind of a design pattern or idiom for it?

Comment: You could have a ModInt that has the modulus as a pointer to avoid the issue of differences.  But then again having the ability to hjave different ranges for each value is probably beneficial..  You can't change the way that operators work in the language apart from by overloading based upon type.

Comment: @Pete: I don't understand how pointers change anything, can you clarify?

Comment: This sounds like something that in Haskell could be handled by reflection: https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/thoughtpolice/using-reflection

Answer (score 0):

Hope I'm understanding your question correctly. In a nutshell I guess you want decide at run-time how a set of overloaded arithmetic operations behave. Would something like this work?

```
struct Arithmetic;

struct MyInt {
    int value;
    MyInt operator+(const MyInt& other);
    static void StandardArithmetic();
    static void ModularArithmetic();
    static Arithmetic* arithmetic;
};

struct Arithmetic { virtual MyInt Add( MyInt, MyInt ) const = 0; };

struct StandardArithmetic : public Arithmetic {
    virtual MyInt Add( MyInt a, MyInt b) const {
        MyInt result = {a.value + b.value};
        return result;
    }
};

struct ModularArithmetic : public Arithmetic { /* ... */ };
```

And in the `.cpp`:

```
Arithmetic * MyInt::Arithmetic = 0;
void MyInt StandardArithmetic() {
    delete arithmetic;
    arithmetic = new StandardArithmetic;
}
/* ... */
MyInt MyInt::operator+(const MyInt& other) const {
    return arithmetic->add(*this, other);
}
```

Using this you can easily switch between different types of arithmetic by invoking `MyInt::Arithmetic`. You could also store the arithmetic pointer away in e.g. a static member of the abstract base class, which would make sense if you want to implement various arithmetic operations.

Comment: You're understanding the original problem correctly, but not the reason why your solution is inadequate. Your solution is just the one I mentioned in the question myself (it's #2), and has the problems I mentioned in the question. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: Okay, great.Would you mind commenting on what you mean in #2 by "each modulus is stored inside each integer". Because I don't see where duplicated information is stored in this approach. Being a static member, arithmetic is stored only once inside MyInt.

Comment: All you're doing is storing a pointer to the modulus instead of the modulus itself; conceptually it's exactly the same problem: what if you get two different numbers with different arithmetic context pointers? Which one do you use?

Comment: Well, I kind of disagree. Firstly, it is not true that you have to store the modulus (or let's say the arithmetic type) with each number. In the implementation above, you store it with each number _type_, not each _instance_. In that case the overhead is negligible. Then, the current arithmetic to use could be stored statically in the arithmetic base class. This way it is impossible to get two numbers with different arithmetic pointers.

Comment: Two things: (1) I don't understand how "the overhead is negligible"? Either way you're adding an extra field to the number, whether it's a pointer or an integer. The overhead is exactly the same. (2) If you're going to store something in a static field (hopefully one that's thread-local!) then how is this any different from using thread-local storage the way I mentioned earlier? In that case you don't even need a pointer to be stored anywhere, since it's a member and you already have access to it directly...

Comment: I'm just trying to help out here. I guess there is no good solution and I guess you already explored all the obvious options.

Answer (score -1):

1. Nope.
2. No idea. Try tagging every reasonably popular language. I'm sure that nobody would have a problem.
3. Why in God's name should there be a pattern or idiom to cover every possible problem everybody might find in a language? Why should every solution suddenly become a pattern or idiom? Can't it just be a solution to a problem? Seriously.

That said, a small modification to `foo` can probably yield the desired result.

```
template<typename T, typename F, typename F2>
T foo(T a, T b, T c, T d, F func, F2 mod) { return func() / (mod(a) * d - mod(b) * c); }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto mod = [](int i) { return ModInt(i, modulus); };
    return foo(1, 2, 3, 4, []{ return +1; }, mod) + foo(4, 3, 2, 1, []{ return -1; }, mod);
}
```

Since every use of `mod` uses the same local, it's impossible for `ModInt` to ever have different modulos. And since `mod` is only invoked when operator precedence and such requires it and any locals are destroyed and their storage re-used, then we're golden w.r.t. storage space. (Also, seriously, a few integers on the stack? Not a big deal.)

But inherently, modulo arithmetic *is* a property of the operators involved. That is how it is defined and how it works. You can hack around it but no matter what you do, it's gonna suck at least a little. You need a user-defined operator but you can't pass a user-defined function for two primitive types implicitly, and nor should you be able to.

Comment: The last sentence makes me feel like you misunderstood the problem. This has nothing to do with whether I'm working with primitive types or not. Even if I had `ModInt`, it wouldn't solve anything by itself. I would need to store the modulus inside each integer, which is both a space inefficiency and inherently wrong because now `foo` will choke on the vast majority of possible inputs (namely, any inputs with different moduli), and I *should* be easily able to prevent that statically. The problem is really that the modulus is a property of the operators rather than the individual numbers.